# Accessing javascript resource under a Rails Engine throws net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, passenger, rails-engines, rails-assets

I have a Rails 4.2.1 application with multiple engines under it. The application has been hosted in production with Apache2 and Passenger and was working fine till a few weeks back. I am now facing a strange problem and unable to load assets under one particular engine and get the error **"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"** when trying to load javascript or other asset files under a particular engine.
The application structure is

- Root

  - AssessmentTools (app->assets->javascript->assessment_tools->angular.js)
  - QuestionBankTools (app->assets->javascript->question_bank_tools->angular.js)

All seems to work fine when loading resources under AssessmentTools (http:///assets/assessment_tools/angular.js), but fails for QuestionBankTools (http:///assets/question_bank_tools/angular.js).

Also, everything seems to work fine on localhost and even in a VM that i hosted on my development machine (with app running behind Apache2 and Passenger), but the problem appears when i host it on server behind a proper a domain.

I have tried cleaning up the server and re-installing the application but without success. I am not able to figure out what could have changed in the past weeks to create this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the problem turned out to be an over eager firewall filter introduced by the data server admin. They had blocked off all url having particular keywords in it. 
Fixed the firewall and all is well.